# How do you say "vroom / gas feed"?

Tags: word-request, terminology

On a motorbike or a car, you control the gas feed rate by turning the right handle (motorbike) or pushing down the gas pedal (car). When the gas feed increases, the "vroom" (noise and vibration) also increases. I'm looking for (technical) words to describe such measures:

- The amount of "vroom" (noise and vibration)
- The level of the gas feed
- The measurement of $ vroom / gas feed $

Comment: Do you mean revs / fuel consumption / miles per gallon ?

Comment: "vroom" is how I'm calling the amount of noise and vibration caused by increase fuel feed. "rev" *might* be the word for that. "fuel feed" is what (I think) is controlled by turning the bike handle or stepping on the car's gas pedal.

Comment: The amount of fuel going into the engine is controlled by the handle/pedal. This does not directly correspond (but does directly cause) the different engine rev levels (going uphill uses more fuel to achieve the same revs for instance). The change in revs usually causes a pitch change rather than volume change (although there will be some variation depending on harmonic frequency, and the difference from idling to under strain). You don't usually measure the amount of revs per feed level as they can be different depending on the situation (up/downhill). Usually just fuel/distance (MPG)

Answer (score 1):

You'd typically hear the word "rev(s)" to describe this, which is shorthand for "revolutions per minute" (RPM), which is the measure you'd see on the dial in a car.

From this we derive such phrasings as:

> He had the gas on 3,000 **revs**. (noun)
>
> Can you **rev** the engine a bit, please? (verb)

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you call 'vroom' I would simply call '[sound](https://www.matfoundrygroup.com/News%20and%20Blog/Orchestrating_Your_Engine_Why_Sound_is_Important)'. I don't know if there is a specific mesure for the amount of car sound. I only know the general term 'volume'.